# Turn off magento "print" message in header

Tags: magento, translation, magento-1.7, multilingual

Just recently I used magento front end translation tool, and after I turned it off I get this `print('');` message at the top of my web pages and I cant turn it off or hide. Any idea how to do that and why it appeared there?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the name of translation tool or is it about built-in Inline Translation?

Comment: its built-in translation tool that comes with magento 1.5.1.0 that once enabled from admin allow editing translation from front end pages

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it have been caused by inline translation. However you may want to check contents of your translations for any suspicious characters or quotes

```
SELECT *
FROM `core_translate`
```

also check the file system for possible matches for example in templates

```
grep -rnw '/path/to/magento/' -e "print('');"
```